# Java MergeSort Algorithm recursive

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, recursion

i have a small question.
I try to implement the merge sort algorithm recursive.

```
int sort_list[] = {5, 9, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 0};
int[] left = new int[sort_list.length];
int[] right = new int[sort_list.length];

public Mergesort() {
    int[] lv_sorted_list = mergeSort(sort_list);
    for (int i = 0; i < lv_sorted_list.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(" " + lv_sorted_list[i] + ", ");
    }
}

int[] mergeSort(int[] iv_sort_list) {

   for (int i = 0; i < iv_sort_list.length; i++) {
       System.out.print("Divide: " + iv_sort_list[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    if (iv_sort_list.length > 1) {
        left = mergeSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(iv_sort_list, 0, iv_sort_list.length / 2)); 
        right = mergeSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(iv_sort_list, iv_sort_list.length / 2, iv_sort_list.length)); 
    } 
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int[] sorted_list = new int[left.length + right.length];
    while (i < left.length && j < right.length) {
        if (left[i] > right[j]) {
            int tmp = left[i];
            left[i] = right[j];
            right[j] = tmp;
            System.arraycopy(left, 0, sorted_list, 0, left.length);
            System.arraycopy(right, 0, sorted_list, left.length, right.length);
            i++;
            j++;
        }else{
            break;
        }
    return sorted_list;
}
```

Now my Question:

`left = mergeSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(iv_sort_list, 0, iv_sort_list.length)); 
right = mergeSort(Arrays.copyOfRange(iv_sort_list, iv_sort_list.length, iv_sort_list.length));`

If i try to assign my left / right array "mergeSort(...)", then it will be assign only a new array with new length, which contains in every position the value 0.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the base case `iv_sort_list.length = 1` or `iv_sort_list.length = 2` (depends on your implementation) in your recursion function.

Your `left[]` and `right[]` should be declare inside each recursion call? As you are using there `length` property a lot, you will get wrong if you declare as global with a fixed length.

Also your merging code seems a bit messy, I have modified a bit and now it should work, please see the example here: [Merge Sort (Java) demo](http://ideone.com/ColC0I)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help and your demo :)
I'll try to understand it and implement it by my own

Comment: @Reptain no problem, please tell me if you need more help